# Initializing JQuery for Server Side DOM

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using datatables.net for a web application developed by ASP.NET and C# for backend code. I have a `<div>` with the property `runat=“server”`. I am filling this div with the html table structure from code behind using the function InnerHtml.

Now, when I initialize the datatable by calling Jquery, datatable is not working. However, in the same aspx page, i have another table which does not runat server and is working fine.

How do I overcome this issue. In other word, how will I utilize jquery for DOM that runs on server side?

UPDATE ——
After discuession, we came to know my issue has nothing to do with Jquery & runat server. I have a problem with table mark up.

When I validate my html code for the table, it shows me an error 
Attribute key-cell not allowed on element td at this point.

Here is what I have for each td tag

hello

I am storing key-cell data so i can identify later this cell belongs to which record in database.

Still looking for your guidance.

Comment: I don't think `runat="server"` is your problem. How are you making the call to datatable? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: The table is rendering perfectly fine with all expected data. The only issue is I am trying to initialize the plugin mentioned in the question to add additional features to the table such as sorting, search table etc. this is not working on the table with run at server. On the other hand, it is working fine on the second table i have in the same page which is built without runat server and is a static (only html and no code behind involved)

Comment: I understand that but I'm not convinced the difference is the server side rendering. Are you trying to initiate the plugin before the page is done loading? Are there any errors in the browser console? Show the javascript code.

Comment: I am running script inside document.ready at the bottom of the page. I have on error in the console which states: jquery.deffered exception: cannot read property mData of undefined

Comment: One more thing is unique about the subject table. I have some rows with only one cell taking the width of the whole table (section title)

Comment: Focus on that jquey error. That is not related to server side rendering of the HTML.

Comment: Thanks Crowcoder. You directed me to right direction and will write here once resolved.

Comment: It appears you were right - please check ny updates on the question